# What is sign_getplaced? And how I use it?

Tags: signs

**Background**

As regards the usecase, I have written [this plugin, named `vim-softwrap`](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap) to allow showing the current line wrapped on top of the real line when `nowrap` is active. It's a bit like having `wrap` on the current line only (not quite, as the wrapped line covers the lines below the current line, but I'm happy with it).

This plugin needs to compute the screen colum at which the text in a buffer starts, which means taking into account the vertical columns occupied by line numbers and/or fold and/or ***signs***.

**The question**

In `v:versionlong >= 8023627`, there's a `textoff` member to `getwininfo`'s output which contains exactly the quantity I want. But in older versions, there's no such a member, so I tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315925/get-usable-window-width-in-vim-script/26318602#26318602) to my usecase, but apparently I've simply not understood what to expect from `sign_getplaced`, not even reading the help, so I can't fix [a bug in my plugin](https://github.com/Aster89/vim-softwrap/issues/1).

What does `sign_getplaced` do? Why does the output of `sign_getplaced()`, `[]`, differ from `sign_getplaced(bufname())`, `[{'signs': [], 'bufnr': 1}]` (I'm assuming `echo`ing those two in a `vim -u NONE` session)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help getwininfo()` returns informations about the given window or about all windows while `:help sign_getplaced()` returns a list of signs placed in the given buffer or in all buffers.

So, assuming you managed to get the buffer currently displayed in the window you are interested in, you can test if the list returned by `sign_getplaced()` is `:help empty()`.

This:

```
[{'signs': [], 'bufnr': 1}]
```

means that there is no sign placed in buffer number 1, but that information is useless in isolation. The exact number of extra columns depends on other parameters, like `:help 'signcolumn'`, `:help 'numberwidth'`, or the number of characters used for the sign's `text`.

Comment: I know that signs are not the only factor. My attempt to manually compute `textoff` was `let textoff = ((&number||&relativenumber) ? &numberwidth : 0) + &foldcolumn + (empty(sign_getplaced()) ? 0 : 2)`, but `sign_getplaced` returns the working value when other windows are open (I think when those have signs, but I have to verify).

Comment: You must pass the buffer that is displayed in the window you are interested in.

Comment: Also, `&numberwidth` is the minimum width of the column. The actual width might be bigger if there are more digits in the last line number than in the option's value.

Comment: As regards your second comment, yep, [I know of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315925/get-usable-window-width-in-vim-script/26318602#comment61677608_26318602) I'll address that. As regards the first comment, I'm interested always in the window where the cursor is, so I'd be tempted to say I need to pass `bufname()`, which means calling `sign_getplaced(bufname())`, but this returns `[{'signs': [], 'bufnr': 1}]` even if there is a sign, say a sign produced by [`vim-gitgutter`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter).

Comment: I think you missed the part about `{group}` in `:help sign_getplaced()`.